# Reading and writing multiple dictionaries to csv file vertically

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dictionary

I got multiple dictionaries in json format 'some.json' looking like these

```
{
  "my_dict" : {
    'key1': 'value1', 
    'key2': 'value2', 
    'key3': 'value3'
  },
  "my_dict2" : {
    'key8': 'value8', 
    'key9': 'value9', 
    'key10': 'value10'
  }
}
```

Both key and value are strings. I would like to export it to `csv` format vertically then read it back to `json` file. For example, when I add an item to my_dict on `csv` format then it would also be added on the `json` file.

Required output

```
my_dict
key1,value1
key2,value2
key3,value3
my_dict2
key8,value8
key9,value9
key10,value10
```

I got so far a solution, but the problem is, the name of the dictionaries are not written on the csv file so can't be read back to json file

```
import pandas as pd

with open('some.json') as f_input:
    df = pd.read_json(f_input)

df = df.bfill(axis='columns')
df.iloc[:, 0].to_csv('some.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=False)
```

Comment: Do you want to write two dict into one file with the name of dict as a separator of each dict?

Comment: @Corralien yes exactly! It is actually more than 2 dict, but I can loop it. The problem is to read it back and write it on the required dict.

Comment: Is it possible to use a dict of dict like `dod = {'my_dict': my_dict, 'my_dict2': my_dict2}` or a similar structure?

Comment: Update your post with a functional sample of your 'some.json' file please.

Comment: Dictionaries are not in "json format", that doesn't make sense. JSON is a *text-based serialization format*

Comment: @Corralien please see my edit

Comment: @Corralien yes it's possible if I use json.loads(f_input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new file with `file.write` for names of dict:

```
import json

with open('some.json') as f:    
    d = json.load(f)  

#sample
d = { "my_dict" : { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, 
      "my_dict2" : { 'key8': 'value8', 'key9': 'value9', 'key10': 'value10'}}
     
with open("some1.csv", 'w') as f:
     for k, v in d.items():
         f.write(k + '\n')
         for k1, v1 in v.items():
             f.write(f"{k1},{v1}\n")
```

---

```
my_dict
key1,value1
key2,value2
key3,value3
my_dict2
key8,value8
key9,value9
key10,value10
```

And for read back:

```
df = pd.read_csv("some1.csv", names=['a','b']) 

m = df['b'].isna()
df['new'] = df['a'].where(m).ffill()
s = df[~m].set_index(['new','a'])['b']

d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{'my_dict': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
 'my_dict2': {'key8': 'value8', 'key9': 'value9', 'key10': 'value10'}}
```

EDIT:

If format should be changed:

```
d = { "my_dict" : { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, 
      "my_dict2" : { 'key8': 'value8', 'key9': 'value9', 'key10': 'value10'}}

with open("some1.csv", 'w') as f:
     for k, v in d.items():
         for k1, v1 in v.items():
             f.write(f"{k},{k1},{v1}\n")
             
my_dict,key1,value1
my_dict,key2,value2
my_dict,key3,value3
my_dict2,key8,value8
my_dict2,key9,value9
my_dict2,key10,value10
```

---

```
s = pd.read_csv("some1.csv", names=['b'], squeeze=True)
print (s)
my_dict   key1      value1
          key2      value2
          key3      value3
my_dict2  key8      value8
          key9      value9
          key10    value10
Name: b, dtype: object


d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{'my_dict': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
 'my_dict2': {'key8': 'value8', 'key9': 'value9', 'key10': 'value10'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your `some.json` file:

```
{
  "my_dict": {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2", 
    "key3": "value3"
  },
  "my_dict2": {
    "key8": "value8", 
    "key9": "value9", 
    "key10": "value10"
  }
}
```

Now you can convert your json file into a csv file:

```
pd.read_json('some.json', orient='index').stack().to_csv('some.csv', header=False)
```

Your `some.csv` file looks like:

```
my_dict,key1,value1
my_dict,key2,value2
my_dict,key3,value3
my_dict2,key8,value8
my_dict2,key9,value9
my_dict2,key10,value10
```

**Note**: with the above format, you can easily use your csv file in Excel if you need it.

The rollback operation:

```
d = pd.read_csv('some.csv', header=None, index_col=0).groupby(0, sort=False) \
      .apply(lambda x: {k: v for k, v in zip(x[1], x[2])}).to_dict()
print(d)

# Output:
{'my_dict': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
 'my_dict2': {'key8': 'value8', 'key9': 'value9', 'key10': 'value10'}}
```

Comment: It works wonderful until I got an error when i read it back `ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.`

Comment: it works but the output is sorted alphabetically. So for example my_dict is zebra and my_dict2 is apple on my json file. The output would be `{'apple':...}, {'zebra':...}`

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to keep the order of your original json file, set `sort=False` as parameter of `groupby` else remove it.

Answer (score 1):

A little hacky but produces exactly the input you are after:

```py
[f'{col}\n{df[col].dropna().to_csv(header=False)}' for col in df.columns)]
```

You can either `''.join(...)` and then write in a single go or add `mode='a',` to `to_csv` so that the output is appended directly to some file.